# Unable to Display Records In LWC Datatable

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

i am unable to get data in LWC table even after condition "someCondition" is true on HTML template,but able to get the details in console log? can anyone help me in this??

HTML :

```html
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<template>
    <div>
<template if:false={someCondition}>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header="Split Contracts">

        <div class="datatable-container">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={contracts}
                columns={contractFields}

                onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
            ></lightning-datatable>
        </div>

        <div if:true={waitingForResponse}>
            <lightning-spinner variant="brand" alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
        </div>

        <div slot="footer" class="row right-align">
            <lightning-button 
                variant="neutral" 
                label="Cancel" 
                onclick={closeQuickAction}
            ></lightning-button>

            <div if:false={hasSelectedSecondaryContracts}>
                <lightning-button
                    variant="brand"
                    label="Next"
                    class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                    onclick={handleNext}
                ></lightning-button>
            </div>
            <div if:true={hasSelectedSecondaryContracts}>
                <lightning-button
                    variant="brand"
                    label="Submit"
                    class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                    onclick={handleSubmit}
                ></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
<template if:true={someCondition}>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header="Contract Details">
       
        <div class="datatable-container">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={consub}
                columns={confields}
                data-id="my-datatable"

        
            ></lightning-datatable>
        </div>
        
        <div if:true={waitingForResponse}>
            <lightning-spinner variant="brand" alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
        </div>

        <div slot="footer" class="row right-align">
            <lightning-button 
                variant="neutral" 
                label="Cancel" 
                onclick={closeQuickAction}
            ></lightning-button>

            <div>
                <lightning-button
                    variant="brand"
                    label="Save"
                    class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                    onclick={save}
                ></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>

</div>
</template>
```

JS file:

```js
import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import helperfile from './splitcontractshelper'; // helper class

export default class Splitcontacts extends LightningElement {
    @track isInitialized = false;

    @track contractFields; // used to define the schema for the data table
    @track contracts; // used as an immutable array of the contracts fetched so any actions made by the user a reversible
    @track filteredContracts; // actual contracts array being displayed
    @track consub = [];
    @track confields= [];
    @track someCondition = false;
    

    @track hasSelectedSecondaryContracts = false;
    @track selectedRows = [];
    @track selectedSecondaryContractIds = null;

    @track waitingForResponse = false; // flag used to conditionally render loading icon when waiting for serve side calls

    _recordId;

    
    @api set recordId(value) {
        this._recordId = value;
        this.initilize();
    }

    
    get recordId() {
        return this._recordId;
    }

    
    async initilize() {
        this.contractFields = helperfile.getContractFields();
        this.contracts = await helperfile.getContracts(this.recordId);
        //this.filteredContracts = helperfile.deepCopyArray(this.contracts);

    }

    
    handleRowSelection(event) {
        this.selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        console.log(this.selectedRows);
    }

   
    async handleNext(event) {
        console.log('Next failed');
        console.log('selectedRows.length:', this.selectedRows.length); 
        if (this.selectedRows.length >= 1) {
            console.log(this.selectedRows);
            //this.selectedSecondaryContractIds = this.selectedRows.map(row => row.Id);

            this.contracts =await helperfile.deepCopyArray(this.selectedRows);
            //console.log(this.contracts);
            const datatableElement = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
            datatableElement.selectedRows = [];
            //datatableElement.maxRowSelection = 1;

            this.hasSelectedSecondaryContracts = true;
        } else {
            this.showInfo("Please Select At Least 1 Subscription");
        }
    }

    
    async handleSubmit(event) {
                
        const fetchedfields = helperfile.getConFields();
        this.confields = fetchedfields;
        console.log('Fields:',this.confields);
        const fetchedData = await helperfile.getCon(this.recordId);
        
            this.consub = fetchedData;
            console.log('Contract record:',this.consub);
            this.someCondition = true;
        /*const datatableElement = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="my-datatable"]');
                if (datatableElement) {
            datatableElement.data = this.consub;
            datatableElement.columns = this.confields;
            } else {
            console.error('Datatable element not found.');
            }*/
    }
    renderedCallback() {
        // Access the Lightning Datatable only when it's available in the DOM
        const datatableElement = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="my-datatable"]');
        console.log('datatableElement:', datatableElement);
        console.log('someCondition:', this.someCondition);
        if (datatableElement) {
            datatableElement.data = this.consub;
            datatableElement.columns = this.confields;
        } else {
            console.error('Datatable element not found.');
        }
    } 
    /**
     * Displays an informational toast message with the specified message.
     * @param {string} message - The message to be displayed in the toast.
     */
    showInfo(message) {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error',
                message: message,
                variant: 'info'
            })
        );
    }

    
    showSuccess() {
        this.closeQuickAction();
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success!',
                message: "Successfully Merged Contracts",
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
    }

    
    showError() {
        this.closeQuickAction();
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error!',
                message: "There was an error merging Contracts",
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );
    }
    
    
    closeQuickAction() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }


}
```

JS HELPER :

```js
import contractsubscriptions from '@salesforce/apex/Synt_ContractSplit.getsubscriptions';
import getselectedsub from '@salesforce/apex/Synt_ContractSplit.getselectedsub';
import contractdetails from '@salesforce/apex/Synt_ContractSplit.getContractDetails';

export default class ManageOrderHelper {
    fieldValues = [];
    ConId=[];

    
    static getContractFields() {
        return [
            { label: 'Product Name', fieldName: 'SBQQ__ProductName__c', hideDefaultActions: true },
            { label: 'Subscription #', fieldName: 'Name', hideDefaultActions: true },
            { label: 'Deployment Type', fieldName: 'SYNT_Deployment_Type__c', hideDefaultActions: true },
            { label: 'Purchase Type', fieldName: 'SYNT_Purchase_Type__c', hideDefaultActions: true, },
            { label: 'Platform', fieldName: 'SYNT_Platform__c', hideDefaultActions: true, },
            { label: 'Segment Key', fieldName: 'SBQQ__SegmentKey__c', hideDefaultActions: true,},
            { 
                label: 'Start Date', fieldName: 'SBQQ__StartDate__c', type: "date-local",
                typeAttributes:{
                    month: "2-digit",
                    day: "2-digit"
                },
                hideDefaultActions: true
            },
            { 
                label: 'End Date', fieldName: 'SBQQ__EndDate__c', type: "date-local",
                typeAttributes:{
                    month: "2-digit",
                    day: "2-digit"
                },
                hideDefaultActions: true 
            }         
        ]
    }
   
    static async getContracts(Contractid) {
        try {
            const result = await contractsubscriptions({ Contractid: Contractid });
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        } 
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    }   
    

    
    static async deepCopyArray(array) {
        const uniqueConIds = new Set();
        console.log('array:',array);
        this.fieldValues = array.map(item => item.SBQQ__SegmentKey__c);
        console.log('fieldValues:',this.fieldValues);
        array.forEach(item => {
            uniqueConIds.add(item.SBQQ__Contract__c);
        });
        
        
        this.ConId = Array.from(uniqueConIds);
        console.log('ConId:', this.ConId);
       
        try {
            // Create an object with the parameters in the correct format
            const params = {
                fieldValues: this.fieldValues,
                Contractid: this.ConId
            };
            console.log('Params:',params);
            const result = await getselectedsub(params);

            console.log('result:', result);
        
            
            const mappedResult = result.map(item => ({ ...item }));
            console.log('mappedResult:', mappedResult);
            return mappedResult;
        
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    static getConFields() {
        return [
            { label: 'Contract Number', fieldName: 'ContractNumber',type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true },
            
            { label: 'Deployment Type', fieldName: 'SYNT_DeploymentType__c',type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true },
            { label: 'Purchase Type', fieldName: 'SYNT_PurchaseType__c',type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true, },
            { label: 'Platform', fieldName: 'SYNT_LegacyPlatform__c', type: 'text',hideDefaultActions: true, },
            
            { 
                label: 'Start Date', fieldName: 'StartDate', type: "date-local",
                typeAttributes:{
                    month: "2-digit",
                    day: "2-digit"
                },
                hideDefaultActions: true
            },
            { 
                label: 'End Date', fieldName: 'EndDate', type: "date-local",
                typeAttributes:{
                    month: "2-digit",
                    day: "2-digit"
                },
                hideDefaultActions: true 
            },         
        ];
    }
    static async getCon(contractId) {
        console.log('conid:',contractId);
        try {
            const result = await contractdetails({contractId: contractId});
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        } 
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    } 
}
```

Apex class

```
public with sharing class Synt_ContractSplit {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    Public static List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> getsubscriptions(Id Contractid){
        
        List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> Subscriptionlist = [Select id,SBQQ__Contract__c,SBQQ__StartDate__c,SBQQ__EndDate__c,name,SYNT_Deployment_Type__c,SYNT_Purchase_Type__c,SYNT_Platform__c,SBQQ__ProductName__c,SBQQ__SegmentKey__c
                                                        from SBQQ__Subscription__c Where SBQQ__Contract__c =: Contractid];
        
        return Subscriptionlist;
    }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    Public static List<Contract> getcontracts(Id Contractid){
        
        List<Contract> Contractlist = [SELECT Id, Status, ContractNumber, SYNT_PlatformForOpportunity__c, StartDate, EndDate, SYNT_DeploymentType__c, SYNT_PurchaseType__c
        FROM Contract Where id =: Contractid];
        
        return Contractlist;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        Public static List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> getselectedsub(list<string> fieldValues,list<id> Contractid ){
        Set<String> fieldValuesSet = new Set<String>(fieldValues); 
        List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> Subscriptionlist = [Select id,SBQQ__Contract__c,SBQQ__StartDate__c,SBQQ__EndDate__c,name,SYNT_Deployment_Type__c,SYNT_Purchase_Type__c,SYNT_Platform__c,SBQQ__ProductName__c,SBQQ__SegmentKey__c
        from SBQQ__Subscription__c Where SBQQ__SegmentKey__c IN : fieldValuesSet AND SBQQ__Contract__c =:Contractid];

        return Subscriptionlist;
        }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Contract getContractDetails(Id contractId) {
        try {
            // Use LIMIT 1 to ensure only one record is returned (if available)
            List<Contract> contracts = [SELECT Id, Status, ContractNumber, SYNT_PlatformForOpportunity__c, StartDate, EndDate, SYNT_DeploymentType__c, SYNT_PurchaseType__c
                FROM Contract WHERE Id = :contractId LIMIT 1];
    
            if (!contracts.isEmpty()) {
                return contracts[0]; // Return the first (and only) contract found
            } else {
                return null; // Return null if no contract with the specified ID is found
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle any exceptions gracefully (e.g., log the error)
            System.debug('An error occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            return null; // Return null in case of an exception
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to SFSE, Exactly which data is not visible? please specify.

Comment: Hi Rahul, data not visible in second table "contract details"

<lightning-quick-action-panel header="Contract Details">
       
        <div class="datatable-container">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={consub}
                columns={confields}
                data-id="my-datatable"

        
            ></lightning-datatable>
        </div>

Comment: Your code looks good to me. try removing the conditions and debug.